# I don't understand how to add a table inside a div

Tags: html, html-table

I have a very simple table and I would like to understand what is incorrect with using this .  I have entered a styling of color: red; just to visualize where the  will work correctly.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=2>
            <div id="transportation_table" >
                <tr>
                    <td align="right"> Flights (round trip) </td>
                    <td align="right"> <input type="text" size="10" id="flights" onblur="calculateTransportation(flights, oversized, shuttle)"> 
                    </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right"> Oversized baggage fee (skis) </td>
                    <td align="right"> <input type="text" size="10" id="oversized" onblur="calculateTransportation(flights, oversized, shuttle)"> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right"> Taxi to airport, shuttle to resort (X2) </td>
                    <td align="right"> <input type="text" size="10" id="shuttle" onblur="calculateTransportation(flights, oversized, shuttle)"> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Where's your javascript?

Comment: Your HTML code it's not correct: you have multiple `tr` inside the outer `tr`

Comment: Your question does not have clear information to understand. Please edit it with proper information

Comment: @bradley your question is not clear. Can you clear it. What do you want to do and also provide your javascript code. It will be bettar if you make a fiddle.

Comment: I guess what you want it's an inner table inside of your td?

Comment: Your HTML is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

You are not declaring a table inside of your div. Tr elements belong inside of tables.

See: http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/tr.html

That is likely the big error you are seeing.

Comment: How is it related to question? It is not mandatory to have `table` within `div`.

Comment: Given the lack of other data for the question and that he has an error, my assumption is that this is the problem that he has.

Comment: Updated answer to remove link to w3schools